# Change Edit Box content when Button is clicked in mfc

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have an Edit Box and a Button on a dialog. How can I change the content in the edit box runtime as the button is clicked? I have to read a new record from a file and post it in the Edit Box as the Button is clicked and I am using mfc.

Answer (score 12):

Once you have trapped the button press, in most cases the easiest way to change text in an Edit Control is:

```
SetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT_ID, "Desired Text String")
```

Where `IDC_EDIT_ID` is the `ID` of the Edit Control (set in the `properties` window)

Answer (score 11):

You can set the text of an Edit control (wrapped by the [`CEdit` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7yhsd2b.aspx) in MFC) by calling the [`SetWindowText` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhczy8bz.aspx), which it inherits from the `CWnd` base class.

So then all you need to do is respond to a click event on your button control. You do this by listening for the [`BN_CLICKED` notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761825.aspx) from the appropriate button control within your parent window's [`OnCommand` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3t3ddsb9.aspx).

Something like:

```
BOOL CMyDialog::OnCommand(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    if (HIWORD(wParam) == BN_CLICKED && LOWORD(lParam) == IDC_MYBUTTON)
    {
        m_Edit.SetWindowText(TEXT("My string"));
    }
    return CWnd::OnCommand(wParam, lParam);
}
```

Obtaining and reading a book on MFC would be very helpful. This is fairly basic stuff, but it's a lot to cover in a single answer if you don't already understand the fundamental concepts.

Using the Class Wizard would make this even easier... Invoke it with the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> keys and follow the on-screen instructions. You'll end up with something like:

```
void CMyDialog::OnMyButton()
{
    m_Edit.SetWindowText(TEXT("My string"));
}
```